# Firebase check value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my firebase database I would like to check whether the "read" key is equalled to "false" However, the if statement below does not seem to work.

```
      ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String true3 = "true";
              for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                  if( ( ds.child("read").getValue() == ("false"))){
                      ds.child("read").getRef().setValue(true3);
                  }

              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      };
      q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ds.child("read").getValue()` will return an `Object` and `obj == "false"` will compare reference not their values so use [`snapshot#getValue(ClassName.class)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E))

```
  if(ds.child("read").getValue(String.class).equals("false")){
  // and always compare String objects with String#equals
```

instead of

```
  if( ( ds.child("read").getValue() == ("false"))){
```

Comment: I believe its giving me a NPE

Comment: then it simply mean something wrong with your firebase relative path reference , post your DB snapshot

Comment: ahh actually the error is Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean